# Angular2 Installing dialog-polyfill for IE11 fails

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

I am trying to get dialogs to work with IE11 and found out that I have to install a polyfill. I tried to install it via npm and get multiple errors and I do not know how to fix them.

**Errors**

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "dialog-polyfill"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package typescript@1.8.10 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/compiler-cli@0.5.0 wants typescript@^1.9.0-dev
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer tsickle@0.1.6 wants typescript@^1.8.0 || ^1.9.0-dev
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/tsc-wrapped@0.2.2 wants typescript@^1.9.0-dev`
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing locally; run this from the directory that contains `package.json`:

```
npm install --save dialog-polyfill
```

If you're still having trouble: try these steps:

- Upgrade to the [latest Node/npm version](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/)
- Run `npm --version` and make sure it's `3.10.x`
- `npm install`
- `npm rebuild`

Comment: Sorry for the late answer but how does this differ to the command without `--save`?

Comment: @moessi774 `--save` will cause the installed package will appear in the `dependencies` section of `package.json`

Comment: And if I do it without `--save` it is just downloading the resources to the node-modules folder right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade npm to 3 or later:

```
npm install -g npm@latest.
```